# Как можно ускорить перебор массива?

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

Есть изображение 1752x1264 точек. Каждая точка содержит значение `False` или `True`.

Сейчас, чтобы получить массив, мы выполняем вот такой код:

```py
for i in range(array.shape[0]):
      for j in range(array.shape[1]):
              if array[i][j] == True:
                   rect.append([[j,i]])
```

В среднем он выполняется 2-3 секунды.

Как можно ускорить его выполнение?

Comment: Можно попробовать написать это через List Comprehension

Comment: @КонстантинКомиссаров - товарищ указал в теге numpy, но его методы не использует. и зря.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проще всего воспользоваться функцией `np.nonzero()`.

пример исходной матрицы:

```
In [29]: a = np.random.choice([True, False], size=(5, 3))

In [30]: a
Out[30]:
array([[False,  True, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False],
       [False, False,  True],
       [False, False,  True]])
```

решение:

```
r_idx, c_idx = np.nonzero(a)
res = np.column_stack((c_idx, r_idx))
```

результат:

```
In [33]: res
Out[33]:
array([[1, 0],
       [1, 2],
       [2, 3],
       [2, 4]], dtype=int64)
```

---

замеры времени выполнения:

```
In [46]: a = np.random.choice([True, False], size=(1752, 1264))

In [47]: %%timeit
    ...: res = np.argwhere(a == True)[:, ::-1]
    ...:
    ...:
44.6 ms ± 539 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [48]: %%timeit
    ...: r_idx, c_idx = np.nonzero(a)
    ...: res = np.column_stack((c_idx, r_idx))
    ...:
    ...:
42.7 ms ± 255 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

---

**UPDATE:** чтобы получить трехмерный массив как в вопросе:

```
res = res.reshape(res.shape[0], 1, -1)
```

Comment: А как получить из [[971 599]
 [972 599]
 [973 599]
 ...
 [941 773]
 [942 773]
 [943 773]]

такой массив
[[[971 599]]

 [[972 599]]

 [[973 599]]

 ...

 [[941 773]]

 [[942 773]]

 [[943 773]]]

Comment: @RayVik, какая должна получиться размерность?

Comment: сейчас (6910, 2), а нужно (6910, 1, 2)

Comment: @RayVik, см. UPDATE в ответе...

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так (пример):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[False, True, False],
       [True, False, True]])
print(a) # исходный массив
print(np.argwhere(a==True)) # ваш результат
```

Соответственно выдаст:

```
[[False  True False]
 [ True False  True]]
[[0 1]
 [1 0]
 [1 2]]
```